# GitLab.com deny access to repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using GitLab.com repositories for git. 
We have created a group of our developers and created there some repositories.

But at last I have a simple question: It is possible to deny the access for single members in an "group repository" - example for an private project, there is only for two members in a group? The project should be in the group namespace.

I am glead to hear from you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - from the `Project Settings`, you can change the visibility level to `Private`. Then, from the `Members` section, you can explicitly give access to each individual user.

Comment: Sorry, but the members from my group still have the access to the project. The group role is developer. But how to completely deny the access to this project / repository?

Comment: @MarcelDeglau Is the project shared from Settings -> Groups? You'll have to unshare it, and if the visibility level it's changed to "Private" from Settings -> Edit project, only you will have access. Afterward, it is possible to invite individual members

Comment: Yes I know this method, but I can not deny any kind of access for an project or saying that an group member could not see a whole project.